# Regular expression to get positive integer and -1

Tags: regex

Below is the text I hope to match:

```
00000001,00000002,00000003
```

It works fine with `((([-1-9]+),)+)?[-1-9]+`.

But it didn't match `-1`. The expression must not match with `-2` or anything else except `-1`.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Should the zeros be part of the match? Why are you using capturing groups? Do you know about alternatives `(?:a|b)`? Have you read a regular expression tutorial? Have you tried your expression with https://regex101.com/?

Comment: Seems your 'working' pattern actually does not match the given text. Show me sample text with `-1` included.

Comment: Zero should be part of the match

Comment: Try [`^(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1)(?:,(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/tRW21f/1) if you need to validate such a comma delimited string.

Comment: Do not answer comments with new comments, edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Wiktor's answer is correct

Comment: @MahJinKhai Always add `@` before users' names in comments, otherwise, we do not get notified. I will post an answer then.

Comment: How does it work fine with your own regex while it doesn't match zeros nor does match entire string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1)(?:,(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tRW21f/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1)` - a non-capturing group matching...

  - `0*[1-9][0-9]*` - zero or mor `0` chars, followed with a non-zero digit followed with any 1 or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `-1` - a `-1` substring
- `(?:,(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1))*` - a non-capturing group quantified with `*` (0 or more) quantifier matching 0 or more repetitions of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `(?:0*[1-9][0-9]*|-1)` - same subpattern as in the beginning (`-1` or a non-zero number with no fractions)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

`[-1-9]+` doesn't match what you're expecting it to match. It matches for example: "-31-23", which is obviously not a number.

A simple regex like:

```
(?:^-1)$|^[0-9]+
```

will match "-1", or any positive integer (including 0001, 00000002, etc...).

Also, depending on the language you're using, it would be simpler to use the language's features to decide if the number is "-1" or any other positive number.

Answer (score 0):

As your state that [`((([-1-9]+),)+)?[-1-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/IMkR1B/1) works fine which captures a positive integer and looking at the title of the question, you might use this regex using [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to capture -1 or only positive integers including `0` or `00000` from a string which could be preceded with zeroes.

The positive integers will be captured in group 1.

[`-[02-9][0-9]*|0*(-?[0-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/yI9gxu/1/)

**Details**

- `-` Match literally
- `[02-9][0-9]*` Match a 0 or digits 2-9 followed by zero or more times a digit. Note that the `-` is not part of the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or else `---` would also match.
- `|` Or
- `0*` Match zero or more times a zero
- `(-?[0-9]+)` Capture in group 1 an optional hyphen followed by one or more times a digit